# How to install php-gtk?

Tags: 10.10, software-installation, php

I can't find it in the repositories.I am using Maverick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phoronix have a deb available](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/misc/php5-gtk-lucid/). It's for Lucid but they claim it works with Maverick.

Otherwise, there are a few other debs floating around the internet.. And then there's compiling it yourself.

Comment: LSB ABI is purely additive,so this should theoretically work.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comprehensive guide I wrote [here](http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/how-install-php-gtk-ubuntu-12-04-debian-17378). The main culprit for most issues is the necessary dependencies and a libtool.m4 problem -- but it's all detailed in that thread. Works fine with Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nobody has packaged it so far. It seems you have to compile it for yourself. There is some documentation how to [install it on Linux](http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/tutorials.installation.linux.php).